# how to put icons in line with other a tags?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

i have just started learning web development and I have been facing a few issues related to the alignment of tags, buttons and icons.

Here are the issues I'm facing:

1. The brand name is not in line with the a tags. i tried **display:inline;** in every class but its not working.
2. the social media tags are hanging in mid air, I want them to be in line with the a tags. Again, i tried reducing the margin, padding and using the inline command but nothing seems to be working.
3. the bootstrap search button is also hanging mid air. I want all the above three to be in line.

Here's a screenshot of the page. [image]

And here's the code

```css
header {
  background: #669999;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
}

.fontsize {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.colors {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

a:hover.colors {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.picturefont {
  font-size: 25;
  font-style: italic;
}

.whitespace {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
}

#margin {
  margin: 0px;
}

.frontpageimage {
  width: 90%;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fontsize"> Brand name </h1>

<nav>

  <a class="colors" href="home.html"> Home </a>
  <a class="colors" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
  <a class="colors" href="recipe.html"> Recipes </a>
  <a class="colors" href="order.html">  Order </a>


  <ul>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#"><img src="icon-insta.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#"><img src="fb-icon.png"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="#"><img src="phone-icon.png"> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</nav>


<form id="margin" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <!--        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> -->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span 
       class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

</header>


<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 whitespace picturefont">
      <a href="recipe.html">
        <img class="frontpageimage" src="oreo-cake.jpg"></a> Chocolate Cake</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 whitespace picturefont">
      <a href="recipe.html">
        <img class="frontpageimage" src="kitkat-cake.jpg"></a> Rasberry Sponge Cake
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 whitespace picturefont">
      <a href="recipe.html">
        <img class="frontpageimage" src="green-cake.jpg"></a> Red Velvet Cake</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 whitespace picturefont">
      <a href="recipe.html">
        <img class="frontpageimage" src="KitKatCake3.jpg"></a> Mango Rose Tart
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slider">
    <div id="slider2">

      <img id="choclatecake" src="oreo-cake.jpg" alt="Moist Chocolate Cake" />
      <img id="choclatecake" src="kitkat-cake.jpg" alt="Moist Chocolate 
     Cake" />
      <img id="choclatecake" src="green-cake.jpg" alt="Moist Chocolate Cake" />
      <img id="choclatecake" src="KitKatCake3.jpg" alt="Moist Chocolate 
    Cake" />

    </div>
  </div>`
```

Forgive me for the improper format but I'm new here. Hoping to find some answers. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the exact screenshot of your requirement for better understanding (How you need it to be).

Comment: your code snippets look incomplete. it is hard to understand if that is an error you have something private that you wanted to hide. Can you provide a better code snippet by ensuring you remove only the confidential data and still leave the "pair tags" in place? for example, there is a closing *nav* tag that is hard to tell where it has been opened.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the best way to organize the layout of a web page is to use tables (rows and columns). Start by sketching the layout and imagining boundaries around the items of your website.

I suggest that you use Bootstrap stylesheet by including the CSS file at your page header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then using the CSS classes `row` and `.col-md-*` for `div` containter element classes.

Refer to the page (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-basic) for code examples.

Your structure might be something like the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">Brand name</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">social media tags</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">navigation</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">search</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">Body</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're right khadijah. but i feel if i start with the col and row classes now ill make a big mess out of this code

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put `h1` tag inside `nav` tag.
2. You have closed the `nav` tag before starting form and you have another closing nav tag later.
3. Same reason as above.

   Try it like this:

   ```
   <nav>
       <h1 class="fontsize"> Brand name </h1>

          <a class="colors" href="home.html"> Home </a>
          <a class="colors" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
          <a class="colors" href="recipe.html"> Recipes </a>
          <a class="colors" href="order.html">  Order </a>


          <ul>
               <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#"><img src="icon-insta.png"></a>
               </li>
               <li class="icon">
                   <a href="#"><img src="fb-icon.png"></a>
               </li>
               <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#"><img src="phone-icon.png"> </a>
               </li>
           </ul>

          <form id="margin" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span 
          class="caret"></span></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                     <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
          </ul> 
   </nav>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@Student, you have a lot going on here, but most of your issues revolve around malformed HTML. So let's go through your issues one-by-one.

> 1) The brand name is not in line with the a tags. i tried
>   display:inline; in every class but its not working.

I'm only seeing your use of `display:inline` in a couple of your classes, but not on the brand name. Regardless, Bootstrap already has a brand with links built in for you. As you can see in the code below.

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="orders.html">Orders</a></li>
            </ul>
...
```

> 2) The social media tags are hanging in mid air, I want them to be in
>   line with the a tags. Again, i tried reducing the margin, padding and
>   using the inline command but nothing seems to be working.

To get these to go on the same line, you can nest the form and the social media icons in a `div` tag that pulls both of them to the right of the navigation bar using the `navbar-right` class. To make sure they're on the same line, use Bootstrap's float class: `pull-left` and `pull-right`. You'll need to add padding to the top of the `a` tags using `padding-top` CSS property. I've done it to one, so you can get an idea of how.

```
<div class="navbar-right">
                <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" style="padding-top: 10px;"><img src="fb-icon.png"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="phone-icon.png"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="icon-insta.png"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

You'll just need to reapply some of your classes.

Comment: Thank you so much @cwanjt . your comment was really helpful and i was able to solve most of my issues. But now the problem is that the home, order, recipe a tags have moved way up and all tags are not in line again.
i tried using margin and padding in the "colors" class from css but for some reason thats not working. I tried using "style" like <ul style="margin:10px;> ...</ul> but this is not working as well.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Sure. Put your code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/), and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: the result on jsfiddle is not the same as the actual result. i really need help